# Is homogeneity of variances required for changepoint analysis?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I want to perform a changepoint analysis with the help of the PELT method: 
[Killick & al](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1438), 
[Killick & Eckley](http://www.lancs.ac.uk/~killick/Pub/KillickEckley2011.pdf)
I assume that the data are normally distributed before and after the changepoint. After reading these two papers I still do not know whether the assumption of equal variance before and after changepoint is required when using the PELT method ?

Comment: The second document provides three changepoint methods: `cpt.mean` to detect changes in mean, `cpt.var` to detect changes in variances, and `cpt.meanvar` to detect changes in both (with "three distributional choices").  Does that not answer the question?

Comment: No. I want to detect a change in mean, but the paper does not say whether the assumption of equal variances is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rebecca Killick herself just answers the question (I sent an email to her). I copy her answer below:

*When using the cpt.mean function with dist='Normal', it is assumed that the variance is constant across the process.  If the variances before and after the changepoint are different then the cpt.meanvar function should be used.  This fits a model with changing mean and variance and also has the dist='Normal' functionality.*